# Cannot get SUM to work in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

I need to have this

```
  GROUP_ID     TOTALSUM       
     1          67,40000000
     2          56,5454
```

With this query

```
 select 
     exam.id, exam.ponderation / totalponderation *  avg(scores.result) as totalsum
 from 
    scores, exam,
    (SELECT SUM(ponderation) AS totalponderation
     FROM exam) AS sumponderation
 where 
     exam.group_id in (91, 93) and exam.id = scores.exam_id
 group by 
     exam.name
```

I tried lots of queries, but nothing works.

Query #1 (doesn't work) `(query error)`

```
select sum(exam.ponderation / totalponderation *  avg(scores.result)) as totalsum
```

Query #2 (doesn't work) (it returns `251 as total`)

```
 select sum( exam.ponderation / totalponderation *  avgscores )
 from scores, exam,
      (SELECT SUM(ponderation) AS totalponderation
       FROM exam) AS sumponderation,
      (SELECT avg(scores.result) AS avgscores
       FROM scores, exam
       where exam.group_id in(91,93)  and exam.id = scores.exam_id) AS avgponderation
```

So... On Can I do a Sum of my column ?

EDIT

My exam table

> id----name-----ponderation----group_id---subject_id----date-
>   1------test1----------150----------4 ------------4-------------2011-11-11 
>    2------test2----------20----------4 ------------4-------------2011-11-11
>   3-------test3---------20---------3--------------4-------------2011-11-11

My scores table

> id----exam_id-----user_id----subject_id   result-------------date------order
>   1------1------------5-------------4 ------------80-------------2011-11-11-------1
>    2------2------------25-------------4 ------------30-------------2011-11-11------0
>    3------1------------5-------------4 ------------61-------------2011-11-11-------1
>    4------2------------25-------------4 ------------80-------------2011-11-11------0

edit: I need to group BY  group_id

```
  GROUP_ID     TOTALSUM       
         1          67,40000000
         2          56,5454
```

Thx

Comment: i have no idea what you are trying to achieve?....

Comment: Do a sum of totalsum ... 
  TOTALSUM       
    56,40000000
    11,0000000

===   67.....

Comment: Nope: still makes no sense, I'm afraid.

Comment: Please, if you say 'Don't work' please specify what errors you get, or what results you get. And specify what results you want. We're not psychic.

Comment: I edited my question for show result error

Comment: @reggie Mysql -unfortunately- is smart enough to understand what is meant here.

Comment: you use "group by exam.name", do that means that you have multiple exams whit the same name? could you please post your table structures and explain in english (insted of sql) what you want to do

Comment: Please provide the actual error. If the trunk of your car won't open, do you tell the garage your car is broken, or do you tell them the trunk won't open? Help people help you.

Comment: code updated for my table structure

Comment: you might want to also indicate what the output you're expecting

Comment: The sample data contains Group_IDs of 3 and 4 but your sample output has 1 and 2. Also Exam_ID 3 doesn't exist in your scores table

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps calculating the avgscores in another inline view before using it may solve your problems

```
SELECT 
e.group_id,
   SUM(e.ponderation /  totalponderation *  avgscores)  TOTAL_sum

FROM 
    exam e

    INNER JOIN (SELECT exam_id, avg(scores.result) avgscores 
         FROM scores
      GROUP BY exam_id) a
    ON e.id = a.exam_id,
    (SELECT SUM(ponderation) AS totalponderation
      FROM exam) AS sumponderation
Group by 
   e.group_id
```

Comment: Thx you're query work 

group by exam.name was my error i think ,  I should use ID instant of exam.name

Comment: humm sorry some mistake =(

I need to do a sum PER Group =/

Comment: I'm planning on updating my answer but you should take away the accepted answer until I do. This will indicate to others from the front page that this is still an open question

Comment: ok thx, I have updated my awnswer with my two table with a edit at the end...  sorry my english is bad , I try to do my best xD

Comment: So .. I need to group my result by GROUP_id  not per  exam.id or exam.name... sorry its my mistake

Comment: thx for edit but dont give me the good result i got  53(group_id 1) and 8 (group_id_2)

Comment: I think the probleme its with the e.ponderation,it only take the ponderation from EXAM  id:1 (20) , so at  SUM(e.ponderation /  totalponderation *  avgscores)   and alway do  (20 / totalponderation & avgscore ), He  must  do  (20 / totalponderation & avgscore ) + (150/totalponderation & avgscore) ( 150 its the ponderation for Id 2 ( exam table)

Comment: I need to Sum EACH exam  with  that exam.ponderation / totalponderation *  avg(scores.result)

Look my first query , The input give me that  exam_id 1 totalsum: 58 exam id 2 totalsum: 10.  So i need do sum  the 2 exam. I need to do that for EACH group.

Comment: I retry your code and that work , but I need one more fix.... when they are NO reult for an exam , ponderation must not be calculate..